# Setting tsconfig.json target breaks paths

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, tsconfig-paths

Here's my import

```
import { test } from "test";
```

These settings will import correctly, but are missing modern TS features

```
//tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "test": ["../test"]
        }
    },
}
```

These settings don't import at all

```
//tsconfig.json
{
    "target": "ESNext",  // added a target
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "test": ["../test"]
        }
    },
}
```

---

If I test through, it appears paths work as expected for ES5, and ES6 and beyond they do not work, nor give any meaningful errors.

---

**What's going on?  Why don't paths work the same in newer targets?  What has changed, and what am I supposed to do about it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"moduleResolution": "node"` must be added for paths to work in ES6 and above

```
//tsconfig.json
{
    "target": "ESNext",  // added a target
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "moduleResolution": "node"
        "paths": {
            "test": ["../test"]
        }
    },
}
```

If you don't include a target, it will be ES5 by default.